# how to get xml content and edit xml file by using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an XML file called `Emails.xml`:

```
<Root>
  <Emails>
     <address>dfg@fds.com</address>
  </Emails>
  <Emails>
    <address>adsfZSdf@.com</address>
  </Emails>
</Root>
```

Um...I'm using visual studio, asp.net. I want to get the addresses by using C# code and also edit one or more addresses(e.g. chage "dfg@fds.com" to "ddfla@fds.com"). 
Furthermore, add new address(es) to this xml file.
(path of xml file is: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Emails.xml)

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you take a look at the `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` classes?

Comment: It seems file path problem T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `XmlDocument` class. Then you can filter to the addresses with a call to `GetElementsByTagName(string)`. From there, modification should be easy.